# Send static method + parameter as parameter

Tags: c#

I'd like to do something like this, but it's not possible.(Cann't convert from 'void' to 'System.Action').

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int n = 2;
        ClassB cb = new ClassB();

        cb.SetMethod(ClassA.MethodA(n)); //Cann't convert 'void' to 'System.Action<int>'

    }
}

public class ClassA
{
    public static void MethodA(int a)
    {
        //code
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    Delegate del;
    public void SetMethod(Action<int> action)
    {
        del = new Delegate(action);
    }
    public void ButtonClick()
    {
        del.Invoke();
    }
}
public delegate void Delegate(int n);
```

I can send the argument "n", as second argument in the "setMethod" method, but I would have to store a variable to after pass to "del.Invoke(PARAM)". I'd like to use "del.Invoke()".

Comment: setMethod has one Action parameter and methodA returns the void parameter, so you have to change the return type of methodA to Action<int>

Comment: @StuartLC even then this code still shouldn't work, the `ClassB.ButtonClick` method is calling invoke on a single param action, but not providing a param. It's a little unclear precisely what they're trying to achieve here... Maybe they just want an Action with no arguments so: `setMethod(() => classA.methodA(n)` as you mentioned?

Comment: Please, follow C# naming guidelines. This little detail makes your code unreadable. Methods should start from uppercase letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of delegates. Delegates represent *methods*, not method *calls*. If you supply arguments to a method, it becomes a method call. So here:

```
cb.setMethod(ClassA.methodA(n));
```

`ClassA.methodA(n)` is a method call, and you can't assign that to a delegate.

Basically, you can't pass the parameter at this stage. You have to pass the parameter when you invoke the delegate. e.g.

```
del.Invoke(5);
```

But you said you want to always write `del.Invoke()`, with no arguments. Well, then you should not use an `Action<int>`, you should just use `Action`, which does not accept any parameters.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int n = 2;
        ClassB cb = new ClassB();

        cb.setMethod(() => ClassA.methodA(n));

    }
}

public class ClassA
{
    public static void methodA(int a)
    {
        //code
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    Delegate del;
    public void setMethod(Action action)
    {
        del = new Delegate(action);
    }
    public void ButtonClick()
    {
        del.Invoke();
    }
}
public delegate void Delegate();
```

Comment: This works fine. Maybe I have a misunderstanding of delegates. Do you think it's a bad practice ? Can you recommend other way or classes to do something like these?

Comment: @eag845 It's hard to say whether this is bad practice or not without context. This per se is okay, I think. If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

cb.setMethod(new Action(ClassA.methodA));

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear whether you want to capture the integer at the call site (e.g. as a closure), or whether you intend passing in a parameter explicitly to the delegate.

Here's the former case, where the value is captured:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var n = 2;
    var cb = new ClassB();
    cb.setMethod(() => ClassA.methodA(n));
}
```

The delegate is thus unaware of the captured variable, and is just defined as:

```
public delegate void Delegate();
```

If however you do intend passing the int at invoke time, then the value for the int needs to be passed in the `ButtonClick`:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var cb = new ClassB();
    cb.setMethod(ClassA.methodA);
}
public class ClassB
{
    Delegate del;
    public void setMethod(Action<int> action)
    {
        del = new Delegate(action);
    }
    public void ButtonClick()
    {
        var n = 2;
        del.Invoke(n);
    }
}
public delegate void Delegate(int n);
```

**Edit - Re Do you think there's a better way**

There's no real reason to explicitly require a delegate. `Action` and `Func` (and `Action<int>`, depending on the above) [are already delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As an improvement, you should check that the action is assigned before invoking it. The null conditional operator will simplify this as `_action?.Invoke()`. But you can go one step further, and prevent the action from ever being unassigned by requiring it in the constructor:

```
public class ClassB
{
    // Can be readonly if it is assigned only ever once, in the ctor.
    private readonly Action _action;

    public ClassB(Action action)
    {
        Contract.Assert(action != null);
        _action = action;
    }

    public void ButtonClick()
    {
        _action(); // i.e. no need for Invoke or null check.
    }
}
```

Comment: `cb.setMethod(() => ClassA.methodA(n))` Works fine =) . In the last case you wrote, I think I don't need Delegate too. But In my case, Do you think there's a better way ?

Comment: Yes, that captures the value of `n` as it was when the `setMethod` subscription was set up. I've added some minor ideas about improving the safety of `ClassB`.